# Validating Arrays And passing field values between each other

Tags: laravel

I am attempting to validate an array from my form inputs. I will need to pass one of my fields' value to an additional form field's custom Rule class in the list of rules for that additional field. How can this be accomplished?

Here is further explanation. After field1 is validated I need to pass that value to the field2 field CustomRule class.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'array' => ['array'],
        'array.*.field1'   => [
            'required',
            'integer',
            'min:1',
            'distinct',
        ],
        'array.*.field2' => [
            'required',
            'integer',
            'min:1',
            new CustomRule(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a validation extension would work:

```
// register the rule in AppServiceProvider.php
Validator::extend('custom_rule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    // field1 is accessible in $parameters. Add your custom validation logic here, for example:
    return $value < $parameters[0];
});
```

Then pass the value of `field1` to the rule as a parameter:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'array' => ['array'],
        'array.*.field1'   => [
            'required',
            'integer',
            'min:1',
            'distinct',
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($this->array as $idx => $val) {
         $rules['array.' . $idx . '.field2'] = [
            'required',
            'integer',
            'min:1',
            'custom_rule:' . $val['field1'],    
         ];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Using a rule object:

```
class CustomRule implements Rule
{
    public $field1;

    public function __construct($field1)
    {
        $this->field1 = $field1;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value < $this->field1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be less than field1.';
    }
}

// loop the array elements
foreach ($this->array as $idx => $val) {
    $rules['array.' . $idx . '.field2'] = [
        'required',
        'integer',
        'min:1',
        new CustomRule($val['field1']),    
     ];
}
```